# Handling get requests in python

Tags: python, html, get

how can I use the IP address of the client that sends the get request?
My goal is to create unique file for each client in which files would be named as the ip address of clients. Sorry I haven't been using Python for a while.

Comment: Which web framework are you using in Python?

Comment: I haven't done anything yet. I am planning to start from here:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the docs. If you plan to use the standard library HTTPServer, you can see that is will send you the client address in your handlers:

[BaseHTTPRequestHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler)

> **class BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler(request, client_address, server)**
>   This class is used to handle the HTTP requests that arrive at the server. By itself, it 
>   cannot respond to any actual HTTP requests; it must be subclassed to
>   handle each request method (e.g. GET or POST). BaseHTTPRequestHandler
>   provides a number of class and instance variables, and methods for use
>   by subclasses.
>
> The handler will parse the request and the headers, then call a method
>   specific to the request type. The method name is constructed from the
>   request. For example, for the request method SPAM, the do_SPAM()
>   method will be called with no arguments. All of the relevant
>   information is stored in instance variables of the handler. Subclasses
>   should not need to override or extend the **init**() method.
>
> ...
>   client_address:
>   Contains a tuple of the form (host, port) referring to the client’s address.

[SimpleHTTPRequestHandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)

> **class SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(request, client_address, server)**

Answer (score 1):

You can import requests module as follows.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user',

auth=('user', 'pass'))

r.status_code

r.encoding

r.json()
```

Much more information can be found with this documentation: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/